# GWT-Platform Proxies

Tags: java, gwt, restlet, gwt-platform

I am totally new to GWT and I am using GWT-Platform (http://code.google.com/p/gwt-platform/).

My GWT client will communicate with an API which is implemented using Restlet. Restlet comes with the GWT serialization through Proxies.

In GWT-P you also have a proxy interface in the presenter but would this be replaced by the Restlet proxy or are they completely seperate things?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The proxies of the GWT-P framework have nothing to do with the client server communication. Their solely purpose is to listen for events that indicate that their associated presenter and view need to be created. As written on the GWT-P site:

> Proxies are the key to a fast MVP web application, they enable code splitting and lazy instantiation of the largest part of your code.

I assume that the Restlet proxies you're referring to deal with the communication between client and server.

So no, they're not a replacement for the GWT-P proxies.